# How can I separate css property using id or class?

Tags: html, css

What I want to do :

```css
div#test { color: green;}
div { color: blue; background-color:white;}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>Text2</span>
</div>
```

I want to apply only `color:green`(not `background-color`) to `div` tag having `id="test"`. But as you can see here, `div` tag with `id="test"` also has `background-color`...

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to overwrite the background color in the ID (Charantej answer) or add a :not to the div rule.
I changed the background to red to make it visible.

```css
div#test { color: green;}
div:not(#test) { color: blue; background-color:red;}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>Text2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add background none property to id

```css
div#test { color: green; background-color:none;}
div { color: blue; background-color:white;}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>Text2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use id like this

```css
#test {
  color: green;
  background: red;
}

div {
  color: blue;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>Text2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the style you want to apply into a class.
Then add that class to an element you want apply the background style to, like so:

```css
div#test { color: green;}
div { color: blue;}
.bg-white { background-color: white;}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>

<div class="bg-white">
  <span>Text2</span>
</div>
```